# Sourcing and compressing txt file, then compressing content to a maximium length value of 50

Tags: python, for-loop, compression

**Introduction and Explaination**

I want to take a two functions (filename and maximum length), where the function is opened, reads all lines, and return strings where the strings defines a line that is filled without exceeding a maximum length defined as a variable (in this case, lineMax = 50 characters)

So the aim is for this is as follows:

```
"['Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting',
'by her sister on the bank, and of having nothing',
'to do: once or twice she had peeped into the book',
'her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or',
'conversations in it, "and what is the use of a',
'book," thought Alice, "without pictures or',
'conversations?"']"
```

The result is that anything can go in as long there is a maximum of 50 characters. the rules defined is that you cannot group together words from different paragraphs, and that no words in the txt file is longer than the maximum length.

**What I have tried**

In thinking about this, I've formulated this psuedocode to see if this would be viable:

```
def consistentLineLength(*file_name): 

# Opening, reading and writing lines from file.
file_name = open('words.txt', 'w')
lines = file_name.readlines()
file_name.writelines(file_name)
lineMax = 50
file_name = open('words.txt', 'r')
text1 = []
text2 = []
text3 = []
text4 = []
text5 = []
text6 = []
text7 = [] # Empty lists/containers for values.

for line in fileread:
    splitLine = line.split(",")
    text1.append(splitLine[0]) # 
    text2.append(splitLine[1].strip()) # Result: ['SAHFS DGDGBD etc'], all compressed up to a value of 50.
text3.append(splitLine[2].strip())
text4.append(splitLine[3].strip())
text5.append(splitLine[4].strip())
text6.append(splitLine[5].strip())
text7.append(splitLine[6].strip()) # .strip() removes backslash \n from ends.
print(line)

lengthlist1 = 0
for length1 in text1:
    if length1 >= 0 and length1 < lineMax: # Needs to be a positive integer number, like this. Should be the max number of characters in a string to fill.
        lengthlist1 += 1
        print (length1)
    
lengthlist2 = 0
for length2 in text2:
    if length2 >= 0 and length2 < lineMax: # Greater than 0, but less than 50.
        lengthlist2 += 1
        print (length2)
    
lengthlist3 = 0
for length3 in text3:
    if length3 >= 0 and length3 < lineMax:
        lengthlist3 += 1
        print (length3)
    
lengthlist4 = 0
for length4 in text4:
    if length4 >= 0 and length4 < lineMax:
        lengthlist4 += 1
        print (length4)
    
lengthlist5 = 0
for length5 in text5:
    if length5 >= 0 and length5 < lineMax:
        lengthlist5 += 1
        print (length5)
    
lengthlist6 = 0
for length6 in text6:
    if length6 >= 0 and length6 < lineMax:
        lengthlist6 += 1
        print (length6)
    
lengthlist7 = 0
for length7 in text7:
    if length7 >= 0 and length7 < lineMax:
        lengthlist7 += 1
        print (length7)

file_name.close() # Close file.
```

So can be seen, this is a for loop solution with separate sentence lengths defined separately. Is there an algorithm which can make this process more efficient and workable for use?

Answer (score 0):

you may use wrap:

```
from textwrap import wrap
text = "1234567890123"
texts = wrap(text, 5)
print(texts)
```

prints

```
['12345', '67890', '123']
```